# How to start the php after yum installed?

Tags: php, linux, yum

After I use `yum` installed the `php7.0`:

```
yum install php70w
```

now how to start it?

```
# whereis php
php: /usr/bin/php /usr/lib64/php /etc/php.d /etc/php.ini /usr/local/bin/php /usr/share/php /usr/share/man/man1/php.1.gz
```

I also can not find the `php-fpm`:
    # find / -name php-fpm

---

I installed apache, in `/usr/local/httpd/`.

---

**EDIT-1**

```
# yum install php7.0 libapache2-mod-php7.0
loaded：fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.163.com
 * epel: mirror.premi.st
 * extras: mirrors.163.com
 * updates: mirrors.163.com
 * webtatic: sp.repo.webtatic.com
No package php7.0
No package libapache2-mod-php7.0
Error: there is no ..
```

Comment: You can either execute PHP scripts directly: `/usr/bin/php /path/to/script.php` or, you will need a webserver with the PHP7 module also installed. Either nginx or apache.

Comment: I installed apache.

Comment: Great, now install the PHP modules: `apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.0` then restart the httpd.

Comment: I use yum can not install `install php7.0 libapache2-mod-php7.0`. see my edit.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

First To see the available options for PHP modules and libraries, you can type this into your system:

```
sudo yum search php-
```

The results are all optional components that you can install. It will give you a short description for each:

```
php-bcmath.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications for using the bcmath library
php-cli.x86_64 : Command-line interface for PHP
php-common.x86_64 : Common files for PHP
php-dba.x86_64 : A database abstraction layer module for PHP applications
php-devel.x86_64 : Files needed for building PHP extensions
php-embedded.x86_64 : PHP library for embedding in applications
php-enchant.x86_64 : Enchant spelling extension for PHP applications
php-fpm.x86_64 : PHP FastCGI Process Manager
php-gd.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications for using the gd graphics library
. . .
```

To get more information about what each module does, you can either search the internet, or you can look at the long description in the package by typing:

```
yum info package_name
```

There will be a lot of output, with one field called Description which will have a longer explanation of the functionality that the module provides.

For example, to find out what the php-fpm module does, we could type this:

```
sudo yum info php-fpm
```

Along with a large amount of other information, you'll find something that looks like this:

```
. . .
Summary     : PHP FastCGI Process Manager
URL         : http://www.php.net/
License     : PHP and Zend and BSD
Description : PHP-FPM (FastCGI Process Manager) is an alternative PHP FastCGI
            : implementation with some additional features useful for sites of
            : any size, especially busier sites.
```

If, after researching, you decide you would like to install a package, you can do so by using the yum install command like we have been doing for our other software.

If we decided that php-fpm is something that we need, we could type:

```
sudo yum install php-fpm
```

If you want to install more than one module, you can do that by listing each one, separated by a space, following the yum install command, like this:

```
sudo yum install package1 package2 ...
```

At this point, your LAMP stack is installed and configured. We should still test out our PHP though.